# Angular service for localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, service, local-storage

So as a project I have been asked to make a small-scale app using Angular. For the localstorage i want to use a seperate js as a service.

What I'm trying to do is use a controller-page to give an html-page the ability to call the localstorage using the service. The reason for this being that I want to access the localstorage from multiple html-pages.

I'm posting my code below and help is greatly appreciated.

profilecontroller:

```
app.controller("ProfileController", function($scope, DataService) {
  $scope.profile = DataService.getProfile();
});
```

profilehtml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1> Overflow test for longer pages </h1> <br>

        <div id = "textholder" ng-repeat="data in profile">
           <span>{{data.id}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

service:

```
app.service("DataService", function(){
  console.log("DataService");

  var localProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

  if(localProfile != undefined && localProfile.length>0)
  { this.profiles = localProfile; }

  else {
    this.profile = [
        { id: "1526", username: "berserk",      password: "berserk",    age: "31",          sex: "male"},
        { id: "1358", username: "Johnathan",    password: "test",       age: "17",          sex: "male"},
        { id: "2539", username: "Britney",      password: "test",       age: "18",          sex: "female"},
        { id: "1486", username: "Kevin",        password: "test",       age: "7",           sex: "male"},
        { id: "7777", username: "jesus",        password: "holy",       age: "unknown",     sex: "male"},
        { id: "6666", username: "satan",        password: "hell",       age: "unknown",     sex: "unknown"}
    ];
  }

  this.getProfile = function() { 
     return this.profile;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in the above code,

(i)You need to inject the DataService to the controller.

(ii) You can just return the profiles as it is without using $scope

```
app.service("DataService", function() {
  console.log("DataService");
  var localProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));
  var profiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

  if (localProfile != undefined && localProfile.length > 0) {
    this.profiles = localProfile;
  } else {
    this.profiles = [{
      id: "1526",
      username: "berserk",
      password: "berserk",
      age: "31"
    }, {
      id: "1358",
      username: "Johnathan",
      password: "test",
      age: "17"
    }, {
      id: "2539",
      username: "Britney",
      password: "test",
      age: "18"
    }, {
      id: "1486",
      username: "Kevin",
      password: "test",
      age: "7"
    }];
  }

  this.getProfile = function() {
    return this.profiles;
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/iA966YB41pbEK6H93taL?p=preview)**

Comment: I altered the code as you suggested, it seems to indeed fix some of the problems I ran into previously. See the code above (which runs without errors it seems).

I now however run into the problem of the page still only showing the h1 text and not the data I'm trying to call. Any idea what could solve that?

Comment: why are you trying to do with | getUser:data? your HTML has some issue, not sure what do you need to display

Comment: It's a filter I made a while ago. It was one of the requirements to work with a self-made filter so I created one. It worked previously, but that was when putting the database in the controller.

The basis of what i'm trying to do is to show the data in whatever way. For now the way i display it is not realy that interesting as long as i am able to show it.

Comment: That might be causing the issue! why you are displaying {{data}} again inside the ng-repeat. which is not necessary

Comment: I can easily alter that entire part. The basis would be the ng-repeat to show the data, i'm simply not sure how to show the data within the ng-repeat. I used an example i found to show the data when it was in the controller, the code doesn't seem to work when dealing with a service though. Honestly I didn't expect it to, but I find it hard to find a working fix as this particular way of coding is apperently not used in other peoples threads...

Comment: Using your example I am definitely able to continue. I just have to find the correct way of calling it now. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm not sure what I did wrong before as your code looks almost identical to what I made before. That kept returning the undefined error and a differend error when injecting the service. Either way, thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a headsup, i fixed the code so it actualy works. I feel prety stupid about the mistake as it was an obvious one, but i thought i should update it so people that look at it later can use it better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the purpose of the localStorage, since you don't initialise it but rather return the initialised profile. Unless you pass the entire array, you'll might lose information if you decided to add a profile. Also the keys for *localProfile* and *profiles* variables are the same i.e. **profile**